# Remove duplicates from multidimensional array using Foreach loop

Tags: php

Hi im a beginner in php i would like to ask how do i remove duplicates from multidimensional array using foreach loop. what do i have have to put inside the print_r part.

```
 while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3))
   {
        $nodecontainer {"id"} = ($row ["left_skill"]);

        foreach ($nodecontainer as $id => $leftskill)
        {
            print_r($nodecontainer);
        }

   }
```

Comment: In the query, you can use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to remove duplicates. So please provide more details like input query, what result you currently getting? what is your expected outcome?

Comment: My left_skill has many duplicates value in the table i just want to remove all the duplicates of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$nodecontainer = [];//define array
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
  $nodecontainer[] = $row ["left_skill"]; //assign all values to array
}

$nodecontainer = array_unique($nodecontainer);//remove duplicate

print_r($nodecontainer); //check final array
```

Note:- BTW I will recommend you to use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` inside query to remove duplicates. No need to do anything then at PHP end.

Comment: is there anyway i can keep this {"id"} inside the array and remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple: extract all id values into their own array, run it through array_unique:

```
$uniquePids = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id']; }, $holder));
```

Comment: How do i use that inside my loop?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use PHP, use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)